# Distribution of proportions relative to sum of random variables

Tags: proportion, lognormal-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid lognormally distributed variables and $X_{sum} = X_1+...+X_n$. What is the distribution of $\frac{X_k}{X_{sum}}$ for each $k$ in $1..n$? What are their density functions?

More broadly, are there any general approaches for answering this kind of question (e.g. with some other distribution than lognormal)? The usual strategy one uses when dealing with, say, finding the distribution of the minimum of a group of variables doesn't seem to yield anything here, since $X_{sum}$ depends on $X_1,...,X_n$.

Comment: The case where the $X_i$ have Gamma distributions is standard and well-known: it is the basis for all the Normal-theory ANOVA tests, for instance.

Comment: There is a strategy to compute the expectation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74199/242321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density functions of convolutions of lognormal distributions do not have closed form expressions in general. As whuber mentioned, the case of the gamma is known. For gamma distributions the ratios have beta distributions.

As an example, suppose $X_1 \sim \mathrm{Gamma} \left( \alpha_1, \beta \right)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathrm{Gamma} \left( \alpha_2, \beta \right),$ with $X_1$ and $X_2$ being independent. 
Then $$ {{X_1} \over {X_1 + X_2}} \sim \mathrm{Beta} \left( \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \right)$$

For your case you will likely need to use simulation, although a beta model could potentially meet your needs depending on how accurate you need it to be.

Comment: Could you give a link or example of how to do it with gamma? I've just started on ANOVA, so I don't see the obvious connection yet.

Comment: I've expanded the answer and added a gamma example.

Comment: It is instructive to work out the case $n=2$, which has a closed form. It might dissuade you from recommending a Gamma approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this problem does not have an algebraic solution. If I had to make inferences in a case such as this I would do a simulation exercise to determine appropriate confidence intervals etc.